# SSO with Sitecore hosted API and 3rd Party Sites

Tags: sso

We have an Sitecore 8.2 u7 Site (e.g mysite.com) and an custom API hosted within it (e.g mysite.com/myapi/)

When users log into the Sitecore site we are using standard .Net Forms Auth and the user is logged in as expected.

We also have 3rd Party apps hosted on different top level domains that make server-side calls the API (e.g myothersite.com). However the API needs to know that the user is logged in to the Sitecore site but as the cookies for the Sitecore site are on another domain the browser does not send these in the request to the API so it does not treat them as logged in.

I need a way to tell the Sitecore the user is logged in when making a request to the API and therefore ensuring Sitecore sets Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated to True in the API when executing the code and not anonymous.

[image]

Matching the machine keys works for .net apps on the same top level domain but not for apps on other top levels domains or other technologies (node,php etc) and I'm struggling to think of the best way to solve this.

Comment: Just to be clear, myothersite.com is making server side API calls to mysite.com/myapi/?

Comment: Yes that’s right. Although we will also need to support JS based web request too. I’m just trying to get server side working first